# python paramiko module socket.error, errno 10060

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

It seems the socket connection through paramiko (v1.10.0) is not stable.

I have two computers. The python code is on the PC one. The connection sometime is successful and sometime is not (Same code). When the PC paramiko code fails (socket.error, 10060), I use my Mac via terminal ssh login the server and everything is fine.

I use set_missing_host_key_policy in the code. But the Mac has the key I guess. I typed yes when login at the first time.

If the unstable connection is caused by the hotkey, how do I get the host key? From the server or somewhere in my local folder (win7)?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching off Windows firewall. It's a network error, it should not be because of SSH key problems.

*Error Code 10060: Connection timeout
Background: The gateway could not receive a timely response from the website you are trying to access. This might indicate that the network is congested, or that the website is experiencing technical difficulties.*