# Paramiko connection succeeds on linux but fails on windows

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko

So, I have this program I made that connects to another computer (*which is a linux machine*) through SSH in python with the help of the library paramiko. I've made all the development on my ubuntu machine at work and it runs just fine on my home gentoo setup. I've been asked to make it work on a windows machine, and I get errors I cannot quite figure out what they mean to be honest, I'm not really confortable in windows environments.

The code is the following :

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.ssh.connect(
    hostname=self.address,
    username=self.username,
    password=self.password
)

self.shell = self.ssh.invoke_shell(width=self.shell_width, height=self.shell_height)

self.transport = paramiko.Transport((self.address, self.port))
self.transport.connect(
    username=self.username,
    password=self.password
)

self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)
```

So basically I have an interactive SSH shell I use to issue commands, and an SFTP connection as well to retrieve the files I created from the SSH session.

When running this code on windows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/labor/PycharmProjects/OPSS/OPSS.py", line 9, in <module>
shell.run("uptime")
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 162, in run
return self.spawn(*args, **kwargs).wait_for_result()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 173, in spawn
channel = self._get_ssh_transport().open_session()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spur\ssh.py", line 251, in _get_ssh_transport
        raise self._connection_error(error)
spur.ssh.ConnectionError: Error creating SSH connection
Original error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I don't really know what the system is trying to tell me when it says the party failed to respond because I can connect to it just fine with WinSCP and PuTTY from windows (which are the two programs I used to test both SSH and SFTP).

As you can tell I'm using PyCharm as my IDE, and I installed paramiko using its package manager on windows (on my linux machines I used pip).

Does anyone know what is happening ? And how can I make it work ? Thanks !

Comment: From my experience, windows server must be configured to accept SSH connections. It's not by default. So your code may be OK, but the remote machine needs a fix.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the remote machine runs on linux, the issue is that my program does not want to connect from windows, but works with other systems.

Comment: See if this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105183/python-paramiko-module-socket-error-errno-10060

Comment: Apparently Windows' firewall on this computer is off as we have a global router firewall within the company. Also I just tried running my software on an Ubuntu virtual machine on this very same computer, and it work, still not on windows though.